# Replace specific colours in a webpage with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I am trying to replace all colours on a webpage with my own pre-defined colours.
I want to replace all mentions of "rgba(29,161,242,1.00)" with "rgb(255 0 0)" using tampermonkey
but I am unsure of how to go about doing it.

Comment: You are probably better off using CSS and/or querySelector methods to target elements (using classes, ids, and element types) to change the color of instead of hardcoding the code to find a specific color value to replace. If they change the tint of their blue a bit, or add some transparency, then the code won't match anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a multi-page app with limited JavaScript functionality, this should work:

```js
const oldColorNormalized = 'rgb(29, 161, 242)'
const newColor = 'rgb(255 0 0)'

document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => {
    if (getComputedStyle(el).color === oldColorNormalized) {
        el.style.color = newColor
    }
})
```

If it's a single-page app or has lots of JS-rendered content, you may need something more complex with [`MutationObserver`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: This kinda worked, If it helps anything I'm trying to recolour twitter and this worked for the initial loading logo but not for the rest of the page that had the same colour